# IIS HTTP Error 500: The requested Page cannot be accessed because related configuration data is invalid

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, application-pool, http-error

I have successfully published an ASP.NET Core website on IIS (version 10) on my local machine (Windows 10) and browsed it.

However, when I deploy it on IIS on another PC (using same versions), it gives *HTTP Error 500.19*:

[image]

I am using the same `Web.config` and *IIS_IUSRS* has permissions on both the virtual directory and config file. I also added the permission for the app pool `IIS AppPool/MyPool' to the virtual directory.  Here is the web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\IdentityServer.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What is problem?

Comment: Do you have the ASP.NET core module installed on the target machine ? https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817246

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It was missing the **NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle**, I have realized that from the web.config "AspNetCoreModule".

You can find the link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis)

Comment: Thank you!!  Hours and hours it took me to find your solution that finally worked.

Comment: what the heck..it is not mentioned anywhere in the official docs..

Comment: thanks. At least passed this phase of error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try giving access to IIS Application pool user to the website directory, sometime if the files are readonly or if the IIS App pool user permissions are not there , this error might popup.