# php - HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: php, laravel, iis, web-config

I am learning to host a php web application on IIS server. I have set it up as website. I have given IIS_USER and  IUSER folder r/w permission. Associate application pool identity "WIN_USER_A" also has this folder access.

When I browse the site I am getting below error. I know that there are related threads out there, but I have either tried them or do not understand. Unfortunately, I am absolutely stuck on this error:([`link1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40684342/iis-http-error-500-the-requested-page-cannot-be-accessed-because-related-config),[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620654/500-19-internal-server-error-the-requested-page-cannot-be-accessed-because-t))

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       Unknown
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x8007000d
Config Error       
Config File    \\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\1_0\version\001\public\web.config
Requested URL      http://beta.test-example:80/
Physical Path      
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined

Config Source:
   -1: 
    0:
```

Web Config

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
        <defaultDocument  enabled="true">
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: have you enabled the rewrite module ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP Error 500.19 with 0x8007000d on IIS7 "Malformed XML" in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132029/http-error-500-19-with-0x8007000d-on-iis7-malformed-xml-in-web-config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message and the web.config settings, I guess you may forget install the url rewrite module. I suggest you could firstly check you have installed the url module in IIS, you can try to delete the rewrite node in web.config. If the PHP application can be accessed normally after deleting the rewrite node, then you have not installed the rewrite module.

If you don’t install the IIS url rewrite module, I suggest you could follow below steps:

1):Visit http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

2):At the bottom of the page you can download the installer without using Web Platform.

3):Run the MSI installer to add the URL Rewrite Module to your server.

[image]

4):Revisit your PHP application.

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.